# PrimeFaces CommandButton: Dynamically enable/disable icon

Tags: jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces's CommandButton allows to specify an icon:

```
<p:commandButton value="Press me" icon="redBall" ... />
```

However, I need to enable/disable the icon depending on a JSF managed bean property.

I tried

```
<p:commandButton value="Press me" icon="#{bean.iconClass}" ... />
```

This works for choosing different icons, but does not allow to disable the icon altogether (i.e. get the same rendering like without the `icon=` attribute). I can return an empty string in `getIconClass()`, but PrimeFaces will still render the extra `<span>` for the icon inside the button, and CSS styling causes this span to be visible with a default icon.

Is there a way to tell PrimeFaces "I want no icon at all" (other than taking out the `icon=` attribute altogether)?

Comment: try to return `null` in `getIconClass()`

Comment: @Daniel: That does not appear to work. If I do that, the default icon is still shown. Apparently, the `null` gets translated to `""` inside JSF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways without duplicating the button.

1. Supply the icon as `<f:attribute>` which is conditionally added by `<c:if>`.

   ```
   <p:commandButton ...>
       <c:if test="#{not empty bean.icon}"><f:attribute name="icon" value="#{bean.icon}" /></c:if>
   </p:commandButton>
   ```

   ---
2. Set a style class which hides the icon altogether and supply it conditionally.

   ```css
   .hideicon .ui-icon { display: none; }
   .hideicon .ui-button-text { padding-left: 1em; }
   ```

   with

   ```
   <p:commandButton ... icon="#{bean.icon}" styleClass="#{empty bean.icon ? 'hideicon' : ''}" />
   ```

Comment: Hm, using <c:if> seems problematic, we may later decide to use Stateless JSF (http://industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/ ), and that would not work with <c:if>. The CSS trick looks a bit ugly, but is probably the best idea.

Comment: That stateless approach should theoretically work if the `<c:if>` condition is view scoped and not request scoped. If it can possibly change on every request while the same view is reused, then it indeed won't work in stateless JSF.

Comment: For now we'll use the CSS approach outlined above. It seemed the least intrusive option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A lame workaround would be to have 2 commandbuttons. One with icon definition and one without. And then render the correct one.

Comment: Yes, that should work, but it's not a nice solution, due to the redundancy.

Comment: True. BalusC CSS solutions doesn't seems that ugly to me.